# Question about this highlighted part of the passage below?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> The other thing is our hand position when we’re driving. It’s nice, soft hands are very important in learning to drive. We don’t want a death grip on that wheel. We want nice, soft hands, like pretty much anything that you do in sports, your hands have to be nice and soft. If your hands are soft and you’re not real tense, you’ll find that you have the ability to steer a car much, much better.
>
> You also want to be able to get the big picture when we’re driving. We don’t want to stare at anything because when you drive, you will follow your eyes. Okay? So if you’re looking to the right or you’re looking to the left and you’re staring **at that portion of the vehicle**, that’s the way the vehicle will move. When people drive a car for the first time, they have a difficult ability to understand how far they are away from the vehicle to the right, and that’s because the right side of the vehicle is a little further away from you than the left. So invariably what they usually do is they stare down to the right side, and what happens when you stare to the right, your car will go to the right. So you want to pick your eyes up. You want to keep your eyes ahead of you looking out ahead and you’ll find that you follow your eyes. So if your eyes are straight ahead the car will have a better chance of going straight.

**at that portion of the vehicle** , which portion? And does the word **the** reffer to your car of the car next to you?

Comment: Does this text come with a video? If so, does the way the person say the sentence in the video help clarify the meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure they mean the portion of **your** vehicle (the one you're driving).

This appears to be written for a country where the driver sits on the left side of the vehicle. So, sitting on the left, if you stare at the objects on the road near the right side of your car, you'll be able to see parts of your car as well (dashboard, door handle, etc.)

Does that help?